# Is there a relative pronoun omitted?

Tags: relative-clauses, free-relative-clauses

> Both Mr. and Mrs. Bacon were looking at Adam now, and he knew he had
>   to make some explanation for letting his good land run free. He said,
>   “I guess I’m a lazy man. And my father didn’t help me when he left me
>   enough to get along on without working.” He dropped his eyes but he
>   could feel the relief on the part of the Bacons. It was not laziness
>   if he was a rich man. Only the poor were lazy. Just as only the poor
>   were ignorant. A rich man who didn’t know anything was spoiled or
>   independent.
>   “Who takes care of the boys?” Mrs. Bacon
>   asked.
>   Adam laughed. “What taking care of **they get**, and it
>   isn’t much, is Lee’s work.”
>   “Lee?”
>   Adam became a little
>   irritated with the questioning. “I only have one man, he said
>   shortly.
>   “You mean the Chinese we saw?” Mrs. Bacon was
>   shocked.
>  (John Steinbeck, East of Eden)

Is there any relative pronoun before ‘they get’, omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No relativizer is required; since a relativizer would replace the object of the verb get it may be omitted (or “replaced with a null relativizer Ø"):

> The money which I earn   ⇨  The money Ø I earn
>   The taking care of which they get > the taking care of Ø they get.